# Pandas - create boolean columns from categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have column Place in Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
**Place**
Berlin
Prague
Mexico
Prague
Mexico
...
```

I'd like to do the following:

```
is_Berlin   is_Prague   is_Mexico
1           0           0
0           1           0
0           0           1
0           1           0
0           0           1
```

I know I can create the columns separately:

```
df['is_Berlin'] = df['Place']
df['is_Prague'] = df['Place']
df['is_Mexico'] = df['Place']
```

And then create a dictionary for each column and apply a map function.

```
#Example just for is_Berlin column
d = {'Berlin': 1,'Prague': 0,'Mexico': 0} 
df['is_Berlin'] = df['is_Berlin'].map(d)
```

But I find this somehow tedious and I believe there is nice pythonic way how do to it.

Comment: Often used / known as "one-hot encoding".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and if need add this new columns to original `DataFrame`, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df.Place.str.get_dummies()
print df1
   Berlin  Mexico  Prague
0       1       0       0
1       0       0       1
2       0       1       0
3       0       0       1
4       0       1       0

df1.columns = ['is_' + col for col in df1.columns]
print df1
   is_Berlin  is_Mexico  is_Prague
0          1          0          0
1          0          0          1
2          0          1          0
3          0          0          1
4          0          1          0
```

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print df
    Place  is_Berlin  is_Mexico  is_Prague
0  Berlin          1          0          0
1  Prague          0          0          1
2  Mexico          0          1          0
3  Prague          0          0          1
4  Mexico          0          1          0

#if there is more columns, you can drop Place column
df = df.drop('Place', axis=1)
print df
   is_Berlin  is_Mexico  is_Prague
0          1          0          0
1          0          0          1
2          0          1          0
3          0          0          1
4          0          1          0
```

Comment: why answering when there is a duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate? Can you give link? But it is possible, I first answering, never find duplicates :(.

Comment: Great! Is there a way how to add those to existing dataframe? Column Place is actually part of my dataframe and I want to replace it by those 3 new columns.